# Copy/paste a row from one worksheet to another produces type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is to move records from a master sheet to other sheets based on criteria from column F.

A type mismatch error occurs in the "Termination" case where it is selecting the cell "B2".

I tried several different options, but each ends up with a different error.

```
Public Sub moveToSheet()

Sheets("Master").Select
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Row
'Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide where to copy based on column F
    ThisValue = Range("F" & x).Value

    Select Case True

    Case ThisValue = "Hiring "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Hiring").Select
        Sheets("Hiring").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("Hiring").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Master").Select
    Case ThisValue = "Re-Hiring "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Hiring").Select
        Sheets("Hiring").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("Hiring").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Case ThisValue = "Termination "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Terminations").Select
        Sheets("Terminations").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("Terminations").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Case ThisValue = "Transfer "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Transfers").Select
        Sheets("Transfers").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("Transfers").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Case ThisValue = "Name Change "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Name Changes").Select
        Sheets("Name Changes").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("Name Changes").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Case ThisValue = "Address Change "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Address Changes").Select
        Sheets("Address Changes").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("Address Changes").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Case Else
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("New Process").Select
        Sheets("New Process").Range("B2:W2500").Clear
        Sheets("New Process").Cells("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Select

Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems, first, you need to use the syntax `Range("B2").Select` to select the cell.  **BUT**, since you selected the entire row from the master sheet, you can't copy the entire row into B2, because the ranges aren't the same size, so you need to select the first cell (A2) instead.

So, the entire case statement should look like this:

```
 Case ThisValue = "Termination "
        Sheets("Master").Cells(x, 2).EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Terminations").Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues

1. No need to `Select`, use variables instead
2. Dim all your variables - help with debugging and learning
3. Some general good practice techniques will help

Here's a (partially) refactored version of your code

```
Public Sub moveToSheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim shMaster As Worksheet, shHiring As Worksheet
    Dim rngMaster As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rw As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shMaster = wb.Worksheets("Master")
    Set shHiring = wb.Worksheets("Hiring")
    ' etc

    ' Find the data
    x = shMaster.UsedRange.Count  ' trick to reset used range
    Set rngMaster = shMaster.UsedRange
    'Loop through each row  NOTE looping thru cells is SLOW.  There are faster ways
    For Each rw In rngMaster.Rows
        ' Decide where to copy based on column F
        Select Case Trim$(rw.Cells(1, 6).Value)  ' Is there really a space on the end?
            Case "Hiring"
                shHiring.[B2:W2500].Clear
                rw.Copy shHiring.[B2]
'            Case ' etc
        End Select
    Next rw
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I basically use to do exactly what you are talking about.  I have a "master" sheet that is several thousand rows and a couple hundred columns.  This basic version only searches in Column Y and then copies rows.  Because other people use this, though, I have several template worksheets that I keep very hidden so you can edit that out if you don't want to use templates.  I also can add additional search variables if needed and simply adding in another couple of lines is easy enough.  So if you wanted to copy rows that match two variables then you'd define another variable `Dim d as Range` and `Set d = shtMaster.Range("A1")` or whatever column you wanted to search the second variable. Then on the If line change it to `If c.Value = "XXX" and d.Value = "YYY"` Then . Finally make sure you add an offset for the new variable with the c.offset (so it would have a line `Set d = d.Offset(1,0)` at the bottom with the other).  It really has turned out to be pretty flexible for me.

```
Sub CreateDeptReport(Extras As String)

    Dim shtRpt As Excel.Worksheet, shtMaster As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LCopyToRow As Long
    Dim LCopyToCol As Long
    Dim arrColsToCopy
    Dim c As Range, x As Integer

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 8, 25, 25, 21, 16, 17, 15, 31, 7) 'which columns to copy ?

    Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet")
    Set c = shtMaster.Range("Y5")  'Start search in Column Y, Row 5

    LCopyToRow = 10 'Start copying data to row 10 in Destination Sheet

    While Len(c.Value) > 0
        'If value in column Y equals defined value, copy to destination sheet
        If c.Value = “XXX” Then

            'only create the new sheet if any records are found
            If shtRpt Is Nothing Then
                'delete any existing sheet
                On Error Resume Next
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination").Delete
                On Error GoTo 0
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVisible
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=shtMaster
                Set shtRpt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtMaster.Index + 1)
                shtRpt.Name = "Destination" 'rename new sheet to Destination
    ‘Optional Information; can edit the next three lines out - 
                Range("F1").Value = "Department Name"
                Range("F2").Value = "Department Head Name"
                Range("B3").Value = Date
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If

            LCopyToCol = 1

            shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

            For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)

                shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = _
                            c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Value

                LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1

            Next x            
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'next row
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Range("A9").Select 'Position on cell A9
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Also, if you wanted then you could remove the screenupdating lines. As stupid as it sounds some people actually like to see excel working at it. With screenupdating off you don't get to see the destination sheet until the copying is completed, but with updating on the screen flickers like crazy because of it trying to refresh when each row is copied.  Some of the older people in my office think that excel is broken when they can't see it happening so I keep screenupdating on most of the time. lol
Also, I like having the templates because all of my reports have quite a few formulas that need to be calculated after the information is broken down so I am able to keep all the formulas where I want them with a template.  Then all I have to do is run the macro to pull from the master sheet and the report is ready to go without any further work.