# Type Mismatch error '13' - Copying WorkSheet Object

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with vba to archive several worksheets into a single worksheet 'Archive DataBase'. I have a separate worksheet 'Archive' that contains the name of the sheets to be archived. I have written down a subroutine that should fulfill the archiving process. However, I am getting a **runtime error '13' - Type Mismatch on Line 17**.
I found similar concerns [VBA- Type mismatch error when trying to copy/paste a row from one worksheet to another. Code provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098576/vba-type-mismatch-error-when-trying-to-copy-paste-a-row-from-one-worksheet-to-a) weren't much help.

```
Sub ArchivetoDB()

    Dim Lrow As Integer
    Dim itr As Integer
    Dim db As Worksheet

    Set db = Worksheets("Archive DataBase")
    Lrow = Worksheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For itr = 2 To Lrow
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
        Worksheets("Archive").Select
        'Select Sheet Name to Archive
        Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & itr).Select
        Worksheets(Selection.Value).Activate
        'Copy selected sheet
        Worksheets(Selection.Value).Cells.Copy
        'Paste sheet to Archive DataBase
        db.Paste
        DoEvents
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next itr

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy the `worksheets` or `cells`? Your question states worksheets but your code is copying cells... Also you may want to read up on avoiding the use of `Select` and `Activate`

Comment: You are trying to open multiple worksheet, which are probably in different workbooks; if you only have the worksheet names in the column you need to identify the workbook and path also. You also need to set a workbook variable using the cell in each loop to open the workbooks. Then you need to loop through each worksheet and copy the sheets to the destination workbook.

Comment: If your range only has the worksheet names, then you could use some of the code you have to assign a `wsname` variable; something like this... `Dim wsname As String` `Set wsname = Sheets(Range("A" & itr).Value)`.

Comment: @allowflyingpig I am trying to copy entire worksheets. Can you propose a workaround to using select, since I am selecting SheetName from a separate worksheet, only containing the names of the workSheets

Comment: @GMalc All my workSheets are in the same workbook e.g there is one parent workbook with 15 WorkSheets that need to be copied (archived) in a separate sheet 'Archive DataBase' in the same workbook.

Comment: @GMalc As per your suggestion, I was able to make the code run, using wsname As WorkSheet. However, every worksheet is copied to a new workbook. Do you have any pointer, how to archive data in the same WorkBook?

Comment: You have one parent workbook with the 15 worksheets that you want to combine into `Archive DataBase.WorkSheets("Archive")`. You don't need to use the list of worksheets just open the workbook and loop through each worksheet, copy the used range and paste to `Worksheets("Archive")` Are your workbooks in the same folder on your computer? if not, what is the full path of your `Archive DataBase` workbook? The rest is easy.

Comment: How many header rows do you have?

Comment: @GMalc 3 Header rows. Sorry, for the late reply

Comment: Please see my edit; it will remove the 3 header rows you identified in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I can understand what you want; per your comments concerning all the worksheets are in the same workbook; This basic code will loop through each worksheet in except the one named "Archive", and Stack each worksheets data in the "Archive" worksheet.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, destSht As Range

Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Archive").[A1]

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Archive" Then
        With ws.UsedRange
            .Offset(3).Resize(.Rows.Count - 3).Copy destSht
            Set destSht = destSht.Offset(.Rows.Count - 3)
        End With
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks alot.
I was wondering, is it possible to not copy header rows from each worksheet? I tried something like this 
    ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2, UsedRange.Columns.Count)